# Node.JS Express form SQL Select query based on supplied parameters

Tags: sql, node.js, express

I am using querystring to get a set of search parameters for the enpoint in a RESTful manner:

> www.api.com/products?name=apple&colour=red

or

> www.api.com/products?name=apple&colour=red&**size=large**

As you can see, not all parameters are mandatory.

To prevent SQL injection I must use placeholders when placing variables into the query:

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name= ? AND colour= ?",
    [
     req.body.name,
     req.body.colour
    ]
```

However, if occasionally the **size** parameter is supplied as well, how do I dynamically create a different query? Writing conditionals for all combinations of search columns seems like a bad solution, and there must be a better way to do this. How do I dynamically create the SQL query based on the supplied search parameters (of course, I would individually check them for validity with express-validator and only allow the correct column names)?

Comment: You could call a stored procedure instead of a free-form query.

Comment: @Matthew, Do you mean Stored Procedure in the DB itself, effectively moving the IF/THEN logic into the DB?

Comment: Yes. Which version of SQL are you running?

Comment: Postgres in this case. To be honest, I was more interested in ways of handling such situations within NodeJS. For example, at validation stage there is a .optional validator...

Comment: `if ( size === 'large') { connection.query... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it safely with string concatenation, as long as you're careful:

```
const conditions = [];
const values = [];

if (req.query.name) { conditions.push(`name=?`); values.push(req.query.name); }
if (req.query.colour) { conditions.push(`colour=?`); values.push(req.query.colour); }
if (req.query.size) { conditions.push(`size=?`); values.push(req.query.size); }

connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM products " + (conditions.length ? ("WHERE " + conditions.join(" AND ")) : ""),
  values,
);
```

But then it's entirely up to you to ensure that the positions in the `values` array match the orders of the `?`s in the query. It's also entirely up to you/your team to maintain the discipline to only concatenate strings that are trusted and not accidentally include user input.

https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/sql provides a safe way to build SQL queries like this. I would do something like:

```
const conditions = [];

if (req.query.name) conditions.push(sql`name=${req.query.name}`);
if (req.query.colour) conditions.push(sql`colour=${req.query.colour}`);
if (req.query.size) conditions.push(sql`size=${req.query.size}`);

connection.query(sql`
  SELECT * FROM products ${
    conditions.length
    ? sql`WHERE ${sql.join(conditions, ' AND ')}`
    : sql``}
`);
```

Like using knex the @database/pg or @databases/mysql drivers combined with the `sql` tag prevent you accidentally creating SQL injection vulnerabilities, but they also let you keep using actual SQL syntax, which adds significant flexibility.

Comment: if I may suggest a correction, we should put the following code in quotes: conditions.length ? ("WHERE " + conditions.join(" AND ")) : ""  ,   Otherwise 'SELECT * FROM...' is being considered a part of the ternary operator

Comment: The `${...}` wrapping it already ensures that the SELECT * FROM ... bit isn’t part of the ternary.

Comment: I am referring to the example at the top of your post, which doesn't have it

Comment: Ah, you're quite right. I didn't read your comment carefully enough. I've edited my answer to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found Knex.js ( [knex like query dynamically add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987113/knex-like-query-dynamically-add)) to be an acceptable option.

If any other options exist, please advice